# punch a clear hole in a UIImage

Tags: swift, cgrect

I'm trying to have a transperant hole in a uiimage This is what I found so far:

```
let hole = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
context.clear(hole)
myImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

but I get nil at : `let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!`

I understand that I need to define current context somewhere but I'm not sure where and how

Comment: What class and method contains this code?

Comment: the view controller that holds my image

Comment: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext docs: "If you are not using a UIView object to do your drawing, however, you must push a valid context onto the stack manually using the UIGraphicsPushContext(_:) function."

Comment: Do you know that is the CGContext i need to send to this func? the uiimage? the hole ? the viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a context available to draw with. Create one explicitly with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, and when you are done drawing, call `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` to clean it up.

Here your code, with the call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, wrapped in an extension method:

```
extension UIImage {
    func imageWithHole(at rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        self.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
        context.clear(rect)
        let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return resultImage
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
let sourceImage = UIImage(named: "sample.jpg")

let imageWithHole = sourceImage?.imageWithHole(at: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
```